# Proving the gcd of two integers expressed as recursive statements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, induction, recursion, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following problem:

Let $a$, $b$ be positive integers and $(x_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of integers defined by the following formulas:

$x_{0}=0$,

$x_{1}=a$,

$x_{n}=x_{n-2}+bx_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Compute $\gcd(x_{n}, x_{n+1})$ for all $n$.

After writing out a few terms, I have noticed that the $\gcd$ appears to be $a$:

$\gcd(x_{0},x_{1}) = \gcd(0,a) = a$

$\gcd(x_{1},x_{2}) = \gcd(a,ab) = a$

$\gcd(x_{2},x_{3}) = \gcd(ab, a+ab^{2}) = \gcd(ab,a(1+b^{2})) = a$

$\gcd(x_{3},x_{4}) = \gcd(a+ab^{2}, 2ab+ab^{3}) = \gcd(a(1+b^{2}), a(2b+b^{3})) = a$

etc.

Now, in order to prove this rigorously, I assume that I would have to show it by induction on n.

The problem with this is that I am having difficulty getting $x_{n}$ into a form where I could easily factor out $a$. I noticed that $x_{5} = a+3ab^{2}+ab^{4}$, and attempted to use this information in order to help me correctly predict the form that $x_{6}$ would take without actually writing it out; however, I was unsuccessful.

I'm not even sure if this is the correct approach for proving recursive statements like this by induction, but if anyone could please help, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: For induction, it's not necessary to get $x_n$ into any kind of explicit form. You just need to show each $\gcd(x_n,x_{n+1})$ is equal to the previous one $\gcd(x_{n-1},x_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\gcd(\color{Blue}{X},\color{Green}{Y})=\gcd(X,Y-X)$. By induction, it also $=\gcd(\color{Blue}{X},\color{Purple}{Y-bX})$ for any $b$.

Then $\gcd(x_n,x_{n+1})=\gcd(\color{Blue}{x_n},\color{Green}{x_{n-1}+bx_n})=\gcd(x_n,\color{Purple}{x_{n-1}})=\gcd(x_{n-1},x_n)$. So induct.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how this is going to show that gcd = a. I thought I would need each $x_{n}$ to be expressly in terms of $a$. I'm not sure how the steps and/or algebra would be like the way you are showing me. Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: @Jessy If $\gcd(x_4,x_5)$ is the same as $\gcd(x_3,x_4)$ is the same as $\gcd(x_2,x_3)$ is the same as $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$, then it suffices to compute $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$. That's how induction works. This answer shows that $g_n:=\gcd(x_n,x_{n+1})$ is the same as $g_{n-1}=\gcd(x_{n-1},x_n)$ for all $n$.